# How To User Getters In Array In This Case

Tags: javascript

Hi guys iam went through the getters and setters docs for javascript.Its understandable when the examples are in objects but i find difficulty when applying the getter concept in an array.So basically what iam trying to do is use getter and filter out the objects from the array.
For example by using getters on the array below to get only the objects with index 0 and 2.Any help would be helpful for me

```
const list = [
    { Name: 'Andrew',id:'234'},
    { Name: 'Jane',id:'784'},
    { Name: 'Kanye',id:'114'}
 ]
```

Expected Output Using Getter

```
const list = [
    { Name: 'Andrew',id:'234'},
    { Name: 'Kanye',id:'114'}
]
```

Comment: Filtering your array, is not really the purpose of a getter.

Comment: Perhaps you should turn your attention to the Array filter method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Understand that but iam trying to get objects based on their index using getters

Comment: How would you want to call this method? `array[2]` for instance is a great way in itself to get and set values

Comment: @TusharShahi Yes thats an simple fix but iam looking for a way with the help of getters

Comment: You should learn more about getters and what are the use cases of it. check out mdn documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd do it with getters:

```
const list = [
    { Name: 'Andrew',id:'234'},
    { Name: 'Jane',id:'784'},
    { Name: 'Kanye',id:'114'}
 ]

Object.defineProperty(window,'listGetter',{get:()=>[list[0],list[2]]})
// the name of the property must be different, getters cannot have a value.
console.log(listGetter)
```

As others have poined out though, this isn't the intended purpose of getters, and you should probably use something like `Array.filter` for this purpose.

Comment: This is what i have been expected and looking for.Array filter is also a good practice but iam looking for a way using the getter for a educational purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns the elements of the array that you want:

```js
const list = [
    { Name: 'Andrew',id:'234'},
    { Name: 'Jane',id:'784'},
    { Name: 'Kanye',id:'114'}
 ]

const getListItems = (arr, idxArr) => {
  return idxArr.map(idx => {
    return arr[idx]
  })
}

const resArr = getListItems(list, [0,2])

console.log(resArr)
```

Comment: need the usage of getters

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```js
const list = [
  { Name: 'Andrew',id:'234'},
  { Name: 'Jane',id:'784'},
  { Name: 'Kanye',id:'114'}
]


const getItems =(list, ...index) => {
  const _list = []
  for(let i of index) _list.push(list[i])
  return _list;
}

console.log(getItems(list, 0,2))
```

Comment: need the usage of getters